# How to generate .key and .crt from PKCS#7

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

I purchased SSL certificate from slss.com and I've downloaded a file to my local pc there are .crt, ca-bundle, and p7b file and I've copied the files to the server and I'm trying to install the cert. to an apache2 web server but it requires a .key file and I don't know how to locate(if it exists) or how to convert one of the files to .key file using openssl or other methods

Comment: When you purchase the certificate, the CA has taken from you a CSR that you generated as the same time as the key. So you should have it around. Also your question will be more on topic on [su] as here things need to be related to programming./

Answer (score 7):

A '.p7b' file only contains certificates and chain certificates (Intermediate CAs), not the private key. The private key already exists, as the provided certificate should be related to the existed private key.
You provided CA with your private key when requested a certificate.
For this, you should further clarify it with CA which provided you with a certificate.

Certificates with '.p7b' extension can be converted in the standard '.pem' format using online services such as https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html or by using [OpenSSL CLI utility](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Command_Line_Utilities) with following command:

```
# openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.p7b -out certificate.pem
```